# nodejs & angularjs: Difficulties in displaying documents & individuals from front-end (via local api service)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have some difficulties in displaying the documents and individual document by gamename from my frontend. I have built with yeoman angularjs-fullstack for the api.

Any helps are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Here is my backend-controller calls:

```
// index get a list of game-repo documents
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    gametitles.find({}, function(err, doc){
        return err ? handleError(res, err)
        : res.json(doc);
    });
 };

// show get an individual game-repo document
exports.show = function(req, res) {
  gametitles.find({gamename: req.params.gamename}, function (err, doc) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!doc) { return res.send(404); }
    return res.json(doc);
  });
 };
```

---

Backend Routing:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./gamerepo.controller');

var router = express.Router();

// crud
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.put('/', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

---

Model:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var GamerepoSchema = new Schema({
    gamename    : String,
    gamekey     : String,
    keystatus   : Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('gametitle', GamerepoSchema);
```

---

sample data from mongodb (json result)

```
[

{
"_id": "546e9483b24b3db23a767945",
"gamename": "Test",
"gamekey": "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX",
"keystatus": true,
"__v": 0
},

{
"_id": "5472d8f53d8d5e510c03b117",
"gamename": "Testing",
"gamekey": "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-YYYYY",
"keystatus": true,
"__v": 0
},

{
"_id": "5472f97d5241e0d90cbb9c2c",
"gamename": "game1234",
"gamekey": "1aa-aaa-aaa",
"keystatus": true,
"__v": 0
},

{
"_id": "5472f97d5241e0d90cbb9c2d",
"gamename": "game1234",
"gamekey": "1bb-bbb-bbb",
"keystatus": true,
"__v": 0
},

{
"_id": "5472f97d5241e0d90cbb9c2e",
"gamename": "game1234",
"gamekey": "1cc-ccc-ccc",
"keystatus": true,
"__v": 0
}

]
```

---

Front-end controller for getting all documents, retrieve.controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('gameRepoApp')
      .controller('RetrieveCtrl', ['$scope', 'gameRepo', RetrieveCtrl]);

    // RetrieveCtrl requires 1 actions of CRUD, R as in retrieve
    function RetrieveCtrl($scope, gameRepo) {

        // get, all gameRepo ('R' in Crud)
        $scope.readall = function(){
            var gameRepo = gameRepo.query(function() {
                $scope.gameRepo = gameRepo;
            });
        };

        // initialize gameRepo controller and services
        $scope.initialize = function(){
            $scope.readall();
        };

        $scope.initialize();
    };
})();
```

---

Front-end retrieve.html:

```
<!-- Gamerepo List View -->
<div class="jumbotron text-center"> <h1>Repo Listing Repo</h1> </div>
<ul class="list-group col-sm-12" ng-repeat="(key, repo) in Gamerepo">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="col-md-9">{{repo.gamename}}</div>
        <span class="label label-info">{{repo.avaliable}}</span>  
        <span class="label label-danger">{{repo.claimed}}</span>
        <button ng-click="view(repo._id)" class="btn-primary">View</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Front-end controller for updating individual document, update.controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('gamerepoApp')
      .controller('UpdateCtrl', ['$scope', 'gameRepo', UpdateCtrl]);

    // UpdateCtrl requires 2 actions of CRUD, 
    // 'R' as in retrieve, 'U' as in update
    function UpdateCtrl($scope, gameRepo) {

        // get, all gameRepo ('R' in Crud)
        $scope.readall = function(){
            var gameRepo = gameRepo.query(function() {
                $scope.gameRepo = gameRepo;
            });
        };

        // put, gameRepo update ('U' in Crud)
        $scope.update = function() {
            $scope.add_gamerepo.id = $scope.add_gamerepo._id;
            var update = gameRepo.update($scope.add_gamerepo, function() {
                $scope.edit($scope.add_gamerepo._id);
            });
        };

        // prepare to add update
        $scope.add = function(id) {
            var add_gamerepo = gameRepo.get({ id: id }, function() {
                $scope.add_gamerepo = add_gamerepo;
            });
        }; 

        // initialize gameRepo controller and services
        $scope.initialize = function(){
            $scope.readall();
            $scope.formData = new gameRepo();
        };

        $scope.initialize();
    };
})();
```

---

Front-end update.html:

```
<!-- Gamerepo Add Gamerepo View -->
<div class="jumbotron text-center"> <h1>Gamerepo Add ( 'U' in Crud )</h1> </div>
<ul class="list-group col-sm-12" ng-repeat="(key, repo) in Gamerepo">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="col-md-9">{{repo.gamename}}</div>
        <button ng-click="add(repo._id)" class="btn-primary">Add</button>
    </li>
</ul>

  <!-- Gamerepo Add Gamerepo Game Keys-->
  <div class="jumbotron text-center"> <h1>Gamerepo Add Game Keys</h1> </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 list-group-item">
    <form class="form-group">
<label> Game Title </label> <input type="text" id="gamename" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Bioshock" ng-model="formData.gamename">     
<label> Game Key </label> <input type="text" id="gamekeys" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" ng-model="formData.gamekeys">
<label for="keyupload">File Upload for Game Keys (.csv)</label> <input type="file" id="gamekeys" ng-model="formData.gamekeys">
<label> Threshold </label> <input type="text" id="threshold" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="10" ng-model="formData.threshold">
    </form>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
    </div>
```

---

Front-end routing:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('gamerepoApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider

      .state('gamerepo-create', {
        url: '/game-repo/create',
        templateUrl: 'app/game-repo/create/create.html',
        controller: 'CreateCtrl'
      })

      .state('gamerepo-retrieve', {
        url: '/game-repo/retrieve',
        templateUrl: 'app/game-repo/retrieve/retrieve.html',
        controller: 'RetrieveCtrl'
      })

      .state('gamerepo-update', {
        url: '/game-repo/update',
        templateUrl: 'app/game-repo/update/update.html',
        controller: 'UpdateCtrl'
      })

      .state('gamerepo-delete', {
        url: '/game-repo/delete',
        templateUrl: 'app/game-repo/delete/delete.html',
        controller: 'DeleteCtrl'

      });
  });
```

---

Front-end service:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('gamerepoApp')
        .factory('gameRepo', ['$resource', gameRepo]);

    function gameRepo($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/game-repo/:id', { id: "@_id" }, 
        {
          'create':  { method: 'POST' },
          'index':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
          'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
          'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
          'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what difficulties you are facing?

Comment: That's a lot of code! Could you maybe narrow it down to just the part that's causing you trouble?